# Easy way to find unmatched quote in vim?

Tags: debugging, vim

I'm writing a ksh script and apparently have an unmatched double quote (`"`) in my code.  Ksh unfortunately just tells me that the last line of the script doesn't match it, but the error is almost certainly well before the end of my script.  I'm writing this in VIM.  Is there some way I can narrow down where the actual quote issue is?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not necessarily a missing quote `"` but it may be that an unclosed right paren `)` or bracket `}` could be masking the quote and causing all subsequent lines to by confused.

Comment: @BrionS True, but in my case it was a quote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably go to the end (`G$`) and search for a double quote backwards (`?"`)

Otherwise, lookup for lines with only one double quote (`/^[^"]*"[^"]*$`) could help if your script is simple.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a terminal that supports color and you turn on syntax highlighting, it should be easy to spot unusually long strings.  To turn on syntax highlighting, go into command mode and type:

`syntax on`

You can read more about syntax highlighting in the vim documentation:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.  Oh well, +1

Comment: Good suggestion, shame I'm on AIXTERM.